# jquery set image to cell on mouseover

Tags: jquery, image, hover, cell

I have a table and i'd like an image to be displayed in the cell that the mouse hovers over. I've looked around and the examples I've found seem overly complex.

Should I have the image already in each cell and just hide/show them?

Answer (score 0):

Using background images for table cells is notoriously difficult, so you're going to need to use a div to achieve the background image affect.  Give it this CSS:

```
td.class td {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   display:none;
}
```

And use this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('td.class').hover(function() {
      $(this).children('img').show();
   },function(){
      $(this).children('img').hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for being misleading I need a normal image not a background, thanks for the reply

Comment: Okay, just replace the `div` with an `img` element. I've updated my solution

Answer (score 0):

Example here with jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/rEETW/

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
        var image;
        $('td').hover(function()
          {
            image = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://maps.google.com/images/experiments/nav_logo78.png');
            $(this).append(image);
          }, function ()
          {
            $(image).remove();
          }); 
    });​
```

Only css, but you will have to put the image in the table first http://jsfiddle.net/rEETW/1/

```
td img
{
 display:none;   
}

td:hover img
{
 display: block;   
}
```

Comment: how can I change it so only cells with class=this are effected?

Comment: I've edited my answer to an other solution, depending how you want your code to work.